# How to open existing tomcat web application project in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, web-applications, eclipse-plugin, tomcat6

I want to open my web application which I made using Terminal/Text Editor on Linux into eclipse on windows.

I tried to open it by doing `Import existing project` but I don't see my servlet files i.e `.java files` in it and i also see error mark on my WEB.XML. 
ty154 is my project name.
My Directory structure is 
 Tomcat -> Webapp->ty154

Ty154->Images & ->webinfo

Webinfo->classes

I have my JSP files in the ty154 folder and Images inside Image folder.
I have my .JAVA and .Class file inside Classes folder.

Please help me how to open and configure my project in eclipse.

Thanks in advance !!

Comment: In eclipse the "Web Application Project" must be in a specific structure. The classes-folder is for the compiled classed and should not contain source-files. For an example, simply create a new "Web Application Project" within eclipse and adapt your "ty154" project to that structure.

Answer (score 3):

Its not possible to import the project that you have created using terminal/text editor in to eclipse.You have to create a Dynamic Web Project under eclipse and copy paste the java files under source directory of the project. The jsp and other html files will go in to WebContents folder of the project. Once this is done the eclipse project can be copied and can be imported in to any other eclipse installations.The best read is:http://goo.gl/hPVapt

Answer (score 0):

As you have written source code in terminal environment so you wouldn't be having an eclipse project file to be imported properly. First you need to create an eclipse project and then you can add source from your code directories. This link describes it pretty well:

http://thusithamabotuwana.wordpress.com/2011/06/15/importing-existing-source-code-into-eclipse/

Answer (score 0):

If you have the war file, then you can import the war file directly in eclipse. Go to `File>import` then select `war`

For this you need to have [Eclipse IDE for Java EE developers](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/)

[image]

Comment: I dont have a WAR FILE. i ll try to create it and will check if it works

Answer (score 0):

The "Import Existing Project" entry only works for Eclipse projects.

In your situation with a simple project I would create a new Dynamic Web project and copy in the sources to the source folder - just Ctrl-c the files outside Eclipse, and Ctrl-v them inside Eclipse - and the static files to the publish location.  You essentially need to know what has been done to ensure it has been done right.